# Using Cauchy-Lipschitz Theorem to prove uniqueness

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

How do I show that the differential equation:

$x^{'}(t)=x^{2}(t)-8x+15$ has unique global solutions $x_1=3$ and $x_2=5$ for their respective intial conditions; that is, other solutions are nonequal to either of $3$ or $5$ for all $t$.

I know it's true because I verified it graphically but I don't see how Cauchy-Lipschitz applies because, if I'm not wrong, the function $f(t,x)=x^{2}(t)-8x+15$ isn't Lipschitz-continuous with respect to $x$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is sufficient for uniqueness to have local Lipschitz conditions or continuous differentiability of $f$ in $x$.

In this case, you can find a Lipschitz constant $L=8$ that is valid on the interval $x\in [0,8]$ and the restriction of any solution to the part with values in this interval is unique. Which obviously includes the constant solutions at the stationary points.

Comment: Thank you! Shouldn't the Lipschitz constant be $L=24$? Since $\left | f(t,x)-f(t,y) \right |=\left | x^{2}-8x-y^{2}+8y \right |\leq (\left | x \right |+\left | y \right |+8)(x-y)$

Comment: As $x+y-8\in [-8,8]$, $L=8$ is the smallest constant on that interval. With coarser estimates one gets larger constants.